# For which solution $(x, y)$ is $x + y$ minimum in this system?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

In the system:

\begin{align} 8y − 3x & \leq 16 \\ 3x + 8y &\geq −18\end{align}

for which solution $(x, y)$ is $x + y$ minimum?

I just tried to find the solution by finding the intersection point which ends up with my answer being, $(-17/3, -1/8)$.
However the answer key says that the actual answer is $(-6, -4)$. I would like to ask the solution for this answer. This is confusing me so much. I would be happy if anyone helped :>

Comment: $(-6,-4)$ does not satisfy $3x+8y \ge -18$. Your answer is correct.

Comment: $(-6,-4)$ doesn't satisfy the second inequality. I found the same result $(-17/3,-1/8)$, which is the intersection point of the two lines

Comment: thank you very much 